# Connecting wireless keyboard to non Apple monitor

Tags: keyboard, wifi

I have just purchased a MacBook Air. I have a non Apple monitor that I wish to use. I have connected the Air and the monitor correctly. My Apple keyboard ( had a previous owner) will not work with the monitor or the Air? How do I get these to work?

Comment: What is your wireless keyboard? Is it Bluetooth or is it really Wi-Fi?

Comment: Mini Display Port is your best bet.

Comment: I honestly don't know but would guess bluetooth? No marking on this thing. Where is the Mini Display port and what do I use to connect? As you can see I am "tech challenged"

Comment: I have tried several new batteries, they are in correctly but no green light shows anywhere. The system Pref. searches..fidsa a keyboard the says no keyboard found. Might be something wrong with this keyboard. will a non apple wireless keyboard work? The apple products are so expensive $69.95 for a mouse alone

Answer (score 1):

Your Apple (Bluetooth) Keyboard doesn't connect to your monitor, but to your Mac. Open System Preferences and go to bluetooth, there you can connect new devices. Make sure the keyboard is on (there's a power button on the side) - a green LED in the top right of the keyboard (front) should light up when you turn it on.

Link: [Apple's Support document with Screenshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201178).